# Can we use external css links while sending fax using html through c# code?

Tags: asp.net-core, interfax

I want to send fax using the external css file in html instead of direct inline css for styling. my question is that is this possible or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we can use both top page head styles and external css